# ADO falha ao conectar

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, vba, excel-vba, ado

Tenho um projeto no Excel onde estou tentando efetuar uma conexão com banco de dados SQL Server. Eu estou trabalhando em uma máquina virtual e o banco está em outra máquina, porém estão tudo na rede, eu já verifiquei o IP da máquina onde está o banco de dados e ele é acessível da máquina virtual, porém toda vez que tento efetuar a conexão com o banco de dados no VBA ela falha.

e me Retorna o seguinte erro;

> [DBNETLIB] [ConnectionOpen(Connect()).] SQL Server inexistente ou
>   acesso negado

abaixo esta o meu código!

```
Private Sub RoundRect2_Click() 

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "192.168.120.152:49172" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "teste" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "root" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "1234" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM cod" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

End Sub
```

Comment: E o erro qual é?

Comment: [DBNETLIB] [ConnectionOpen(Connect()).] SQL Server inexistente ou acesso negado

Comment: por acaso aonde o seu banco esta você já deu as devidas permissões de segurança?

Comment: eu acredito que sim, pois estou estou conectado nele pelo DataGrip

Comment: Pela IDE conecta normal mas se você não de as devidas permissões ao banco onde ele se encontra raramente vai conseguir usar pelas aplicações!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido, no `server_name` estava utilizando `:` para separar a porta de conexão, mas o correto é utilizar `,`.